# How to deal with chameleon schema in svcutil/dotnet_svcutil?

Tags: c#, .net, soap, dotnet-svcutil

OK. The question is straightforward, and I don't know what to say more. It seems `dotnet` haven't provided any solution to deal with SOAP Services using chameleon schema design. Did you have faced this problem before? If so, have you any idea - but moving to another language/framework - how to deal with the issue?

More Info:

I'm trying to create proxy for this `wsdl` by this command:

```
dotnet svcutil "https://some-service/some.wsdl" -wr -ac
```

As you can see, the `wsdl` follows open travel protocol. It creates a lot of warnings until this error occurs:

```
Error: The datatype 'http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05:POS_Type' is missing.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05']/wsdl:portType[@name='SomeServiceName']
```

while the `POS_Type` is defined in XSDs.